# How to use a value as a name of a file?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in JS. I want to change the background image of a div by using values from  tag. I can change the background-color but now I want to use the value as the name of a jpg file. Does anyone know how? The values will be 1,2,3 and the name of the graphic files are 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg.

```
   <div class="container" id="wrapper">
      <form>
        <label for="my-select">Choose the continent:    </label>
        <select
          name=""
          id="my-select"
          value="Choose the continent"
          onChange="myFunction()"
        >
          <option value="default">default</option>
          <option value="1">Asia</option>
          <option value="2">Australia</option>
          <option value="3">South america</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
```

```
  const myWrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;
  myWrapper.style.backgroundImage = url("images/x.jpg");
  }
  // I know the last line won't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, try something like this:

```js
  const myWrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;
  myWrapper.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/" + x + ".jpg)";
  }
```

```html
   <div class="container" id="wrapper">
      <form>
        <label for="my-select">Choose the continent:    </label>
        <select
          name=""
          id="my-select"
          value="Choose the continent"
          onChange="myFunction()"
        >
          <option value="default">default</option>
          <option value="1">Asia</option>
          <option value="2">Australia</option>
          <option value="3">South america</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
```

If you want even more readable code, you can use template literals instead of string concatenation, like this:

```
myWrapper.style.backgroundImage = `url(images/${x}.jpg)`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Solution is mostly correct. You only needed to insert the entire string to the CSS-Styling, as you would normally in CSS.

You then needed to concatenate the X-Value to the string, so it gets the number stored in it instead of the x as a direct character.

```js
const myWrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;

  // You'll need to insert the CSS-Style as an entire string.
  // We concatenate the Variable X to the string, so it gets dynamicly used.
  myWrapper.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/"+x+".jpg')";
}
```

Comment: Do you know why the template literal below doesn't work? url(`images/${x}.jpg`);

Comment: The reason is, that the other solution would access a javascript Function called `url()`, which doesn't exist. You need to store the entire string including `url(...)` as this gets resolved later on runtime from the browser.
It is possible to use the template literals, the only problem was, that the `url()` portion wasn't inside the string.